# Saving changes made to media item with image cropper

Tags: javascript, angularjs, umbraco

I've implemented a custom controller for an image cropper that opens an overlay on a media item in the content section. Right now I can have the overlay display and fiddle around with the crops jut fine, but when I select "Save Crops", the changes are not persisted. If I use the image cropper in the media section, the change is being made correctly.

I looked through the belle docs for the save function of the media resource, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

The docs says to first get the id, and then save in the callback:

```
    mediaResource.getById(1234)
       .then(function(media) {
             media.name = "I want a new name!";
             mediaResource.save(media, false)
               .then(function(media){
                   alert("Retrieved, updated and saved again");
               });
       });
```

In my overlay object I have this submit function:

```
submit: function (model) { //when user clicks save crops button
                    $scope.overlay.saving = true;
                    mediaResource.getById($scope.images[0].udi)
                        .then(function (media) {
                            media.umbracoFile = $scope.overlay.value;
                            mediaResource.save(media, false, []).then(function (media) { //save changes to media item, or craete if new

                                console.log("On saving start end:", $scope);
                                $scope.overlay.saving = false;
                                $scope.overlay.show = false;
                                notificationsService.remove(0);
                                notificationsService.success("The crops for '" + media.name + "' have been saved");
                            });
                        });
                }
```

I get no error response when I hit "Save Crops", which calls the submit function, but the changes are not being saved. I'm unsure which actions I need to perform on the media object to correctly save my changes.

Comment: I'm not sure if I know what you want. The Image Cropper uses predefined crops so they can be used later on  to crop the displayed images. Do you want to give the frontend user the possibility to chose one of those predefined values? Or you want the user to crop the images freely.?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I know what you mean. By default the umbracoFile property of the Image uses the ImageCropper datatype, which stores all the image and crops information in a JSON string with this format:

```
{
"src":"/media/1050/Image1.jpg",
"focalPoint":{"left":0.5,"top":0.5},
"crops":[
    {"alias":"crop1",
    "width":500,
    "height":800,
    "coordinates":{
        "x1":0.30206315789473687,
        "y1":0.0,
        "x2":0.28148947368421051,
        "y2":0.0}
        }
    ]
}
```

You can display this getting the umbracoFile property as string:

```
var data = image.GetPropertyValue("umbracoFile").ToString();
```

So the model passed to your submit function has to recreate all this structure and values.